# Equivalence of Euclidean metric and the metric $d(x,y) = min{1, |x-y|}$ on $\mathbb R^{2}$

Tags: metric-spaces, equivalent-metrics

I'm trying to prove the following example given in my lecture notes:

**Example:** On $\mathbb R^{2}$ , Euclidean metric and the metric $d(x,y) = \min(1, |x-y|)$ are topologically equivalent.

**Initial thoughts:** I know I have to show that there are $0<c,C<\infty$ such that $$cd_1(x,y) \le d_2(x,y) \le Cd_1(x,y) $$

**case i)** $|x-y| \le 1$ which implies $d_2(x,y) = 1$ 
\**case ii)** $|x-y| \gt 1$ which implies $d_2(x,y) = |x-y|$

I tried using the fact that both are basically calculating distance and the following to find $c$ and $C$.

$$\sqrt[]{(p-q)^2} = |p-q|$$

I can't seem to work out a solution.
Alternatively, I could show that all $d_1$ and $d_2$ open sets coincide but I have no idea how to go about that.  Any help appreciated! Sorry about the messy formatting, I'm not used to MathJax.

Comment: What you're asking to show is actually a little bit too strong. You will find that $|x-y| \leq C d(x,y)$ is not possible to attain. What really matters is that if $|x_n-x| \to 0$ then $d(x_n,x) \to 0$ and vice versa, which you can prove. Equivalently, you can prove your result on each bounded subset.

Answer (score 2):

HINT.- Prove that the identity function is continuous from $E_1=(\mathbb R^2,d_1)$ to
$E_2=(\mathbb R^2,d_2)$ and reciprocally (this is not difficult). So you have proved that every open set of $E_2$ is an open set of $E_1$ and viceversa i. e. both topologies are equivalent.

Comment: You are welcome. Actually this is a practical way to prove homeomorphisms but with metric spaces is better for convergent series proving continuity.